# How to obtain continuous data using Python requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am working on a code which will capture sensor readings from a website and store it offline in my system. I am using Python's request library for this. The code looks like this:

```
import requests
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError

Ds2temp = 'url of the site'

try:
    r2 = requests.get(Ds2temp, stream = True)
    r2.raise_for_status()

except HTTPError as http_err:
    print(f'HTTP error occured: {http_err}')
except Exception as err:
    print(f'Other error occured: {err}')
else:
    print('Success!!')

with open('TempNew1.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r2.content)
```

With this code, I obtain the result only once and not in a continuous manner as that in the website. Now, I did some research and found that requests.get() you can use stream = True to enable streaming but so far, what I am obtaining is a single result and the program terminating.

I also put in a for loop to run this for 10 times just for testing purposes but that too fails. It prints Success 10 times and terminates while writing just one value on the file.

Is there a way to obtain continuous sensor values using this library? Any help in this matter would be appreciated.

EDIT: Instead of using w+, I tried using 'a' for append. The code is

```
 with open('TempNew1.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(r2.content)
```

This throws in an error, write() argument must be str, not bytes

Any insights onto this?

Comment: If you want multiple results in a file, you must write to the file within the loop, not at the very end of the program

Comment: @cricket_007 did that but it isn't working.

Comment: Is the data get when you send `requests.get` or it gets updated in the website without need to reload?

Comment: @GuvenDegirmenci In the website, it gets updated without the need to reload

Comment: I wonder if it's a websocket thing or just consistent get request updates. Can you give us more information about the website? From which program is that hosted? Also you can check the `network` tab in developer tools to check what requests are made.

Comment: Can you share the URL with us?